# Mobile phone TRS output to microcontroller digital input?

Tags: microcontroller, audio, communication, iphone

How should a mobile phone headphone audio output (such as the headset jack on top or bottom of an iPhone) be interfaced to a microcontroller digital input? (3.3V controller.  Assume no audio frequency capable A/D is available.)

Assume a modulation scheme such as FSK or similar at appropriate frequencies.

Comment: What do you mean with "Assume no audio frequency capable A/D is available"? Anyway you will probably need an amplifier at least

Comment: Some microcontroller chips either have no built-in ADC, or have one that is very slow (Hz vs kHz)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make sure to put out a single clean frequency at a time, then a zero crossing detector is all you need.  Audio can always be AC coupled, so a comparator or opamp acting as a comparator is all you need.  One input gets filtered 1/2 supply voltage.  The other gets that as DC bias but also gets the AC coupled audio.  This will make a square wave at the audio frequency.  A micro can measure this frequency and interpret its meaning in the context of a higher level protocol.

Note that this won't work for multiple frequencies sent at the same time, like DTMF for example.